# Apache ReverseProxyPass redrects to http rather than https

Tags: apache-2.2, https, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have a reverse proxy setup using apache mod_proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName reverse.server.com  
   ProxyPass / http://10.1.9.11:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.9.11:3000/
   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ...snip ssl stuff...
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine most of the time.  The problem is when the internal server does a redirect.  While the proxypassreverse should catch the location, and it seems to, it redirects to http://reverse.server.com rather than to https://reverse.server.com.  So it is half working, the address changes correctly, but the protocol stays as the internal server.

I am not clear on why it is doing this, as the proxied connection is SSL - any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ProxyPassReverse` can not fix this kind of redirections. There are 2 ways to solve the problem:

- Use HTTPS for the internal site. e.g. `ProxyPass / https:...` and `ProxyPassReverse / https:` (actually the last one is not required in your case).
- Use mod_headers in the reverse proxy: `Header edit Location ^http: https:`
- Use mod_rewrite in the reverse proxy to change the redirection.

Comment: Ah, so this would send http to the browser, I would need to accept http inbound and change to https?  Currently this server is only listening on 443.  Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, to use HTTPS internally.

Comment: Thank you so much :) using `Header edit` solved it for me. This had been driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just experiencing the same issue. We found 2 ideas to try, dont know if it really works:
1/ use the RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Protocol "https"
=> http://toroid.org/ams/etc/mixing-http-and-https

2/ use the variable httpsindicatorheader (it's a websphere) to indicate through the application server that the initial request was https. Then every redirection will be on https

Comment: fwiw, `httpsIndicatorHeader` is documented here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTXQ_9.0.0/admin/config/config_was_web_container.html